# For/to all intents and purposes

Tags: usage

What is the error in the following sentence?

> Although there was still a faint heart beat, the patient was **for all intents and purposes dead**.

On many of the websites I found that instead of **for**, **to** is the correct preposition.

But I think **for** is correct here because **for all intents and purposes** means **almost completely**

Answer (score 1):

Both forms occur, and they mean the same thing. The following Google ngram shows that the version with "to" was once much more frequent, while the version with "for" now occurs almost as much:
[Google ngram "intents and purposes"](https://tinyurl.com/ycgjdsrd)

This reference says that "to" is more common in British English, and "for" is more common in American English:
[Garner's Modern American Usage "for all intents and purposes"](https://tinyurl.com/ydhvbysr)

Apart from the variation in the preposition, it's a fixed phrase meaning "virtually" or "in effect", or "almost completely".